# Ruby IO get directly one packet

Tags: ruby, tcp, timer, io

I have a protocol, working over TCP, which has no line end symbol. Instead of that, the end and the start of protocol should be defined by timing.

So `IO#gets` and `IO#readline` doesnt work because it's no `\n` at the end of packet.

Is it possible to define the end of the packet? For example if it's not new data for some peroid of time - this is packet end?

UPD:

I found such solution, don't know about performance, but it works:

```
class IO
  include Timeout

  #time - time in seconds to wait from last byte to understand packet end
  def gett(time)
    raw = getc
    loop {
      begin
        timeout(time){raw << getc}
      rescue Timeout::Error
        break
      end
    }
    raw
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to make the socket non-blocking, then use non-blocking reads. Those return immediately if no data is available, allowing you to do something timeout-based instead.

Comment: Ruby has [Module:Timeout](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) which allows to rise Exception, if operations takes bigger time than set. Probably I should use this?

Comment: That could work, but I've read a lot of bad stuff about that module regarding performance. There should be a proper way to do it using IO or Socket methods. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with Ruby's sockets.